# How to convert a list of objects to list of attributes?

Tags: python, python-2.x

What is the pythonic way to convert a list of objects such as

```
dic = [{'name':'foo', 'age':23}, {'name':'bar', 'age':25}, {'name':'baz', 'age':28}]
```

to a list of strings like below?

```
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: `[item['name'] for item in dic]`

Comment: Those aren’t just any objects, those are dictionaries, no?

Comment: `list(map(itemgetter('name'), dic))`, for the functional crowd. :o)

Comment: @deceze i’m curious, does Python have much of a functional crowd?

Comment: @deceze There may raise a question, where you got the `attrgetter` from :)

Comment: There's another way(which i don't like), `from operator import itemgetter; lst = list(map(itemgetter('name', dic)))` # ew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension

```
lst = [k['name'] for k in dic]
```

Answer (score 0):

to convert

```
  dic = [{'name':'foo', 'age':23}, {'name':'bar', 'age':25}, {'name':'baz', 'age':28}]
```

to `lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`

use  `lst = [obj['name'] for obj in dic]`

if you have any object in the list and which is access by some attribute the use this

`lst = [object.attribute for object in dic]`